# как создать stored procedure

Tags: sql

как из этого сделать stored procedure

```
SELECT (Authors.Firstname+' '+ Authors.lastname)  as Name, COUNT(books.authorID)  as TotalBooks
FROM  BookSales2, Authors, Books
where BookSales2.BookId=Books.Id and
Books.AuthorID=Authors.ID  
GROUP BY Authors.Firstname, Authors.lastname;
```

так не работает

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TotalofBooks
AS
SELECT (Authors.Firstname+' '+ Authors.lastname)  as Name, COUNT(books.authorID)  as TotalBooks
FROM  BookSales2, Authors, Books
where BookSales2.BookId=Books.Id and
Books.AuthorID=Authors.ID  
GROUP BY Authors.Firstname, Authors.lastname;

GO;
```

Comment: Укажите диалект SQL или название и версию СУБД. У всех СУБД свой способ создания процедур.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Судя по `GO;` у него SQL Server.

Comment: *так не работает* - не работают негры в африке. А тут - либо процедура не создаётся и выводится сообщение об ошибке (какое?), либо процедура не выполняется (а как выполняете?) и выводится сообщение об ошибке (какое?).

Comment: Кинь текст сообщения, может прав не хватает. 
По синтаксису вроде норм, но схему лучше явно указывать.